# How to insert keyvalue as a row in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table variable which contains records in terms of key,value pair of a table. where key is the column of table and value is the value for that column

below is table variable

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE( 
FieldName varchar(100), 
FieldValue varchar(max))

insert into @Table values('Title','NewFrom')
insert into @Table values('Points','4')
insert into @Table values('createdby','5')
```

I have above values in UsersInformation.This is physical table of sql server
has following column.

```
 UserID int autoincrement(identity)
 Title nvarchar(100),
 Points int,
 createdby int
```

I want that all values of @Table should be as a single row of UserInformation table.

How can be using sql server?

Comment: please show us the sample output that you want to insert in user info table and in which column we have to store.

Comment: pivot/unpivot. But this scenario seems very strange. Where are you getting those values (field/value) from? Are they stored in persistent table or are passed to SP as an argument?

Comment: @IvanStarostin - this is dynamic and may code from code.Some time it have 3 columns values, sometimes only 2 values. all columns are allowing null value. any idea?

Comment: You didn't understand my question: are you preparing such `@Table` variable **yourself** before inserting? If so - why are you doing it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested but this should work

```
INSERT INTO UsersInformation (Title, Points, createdby)
SELECT Title, Points, createdby FROM  (SELECT FieldName, FieldValue
FROM  @Table) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (MAX(FieldValue) FOR FieldName IN ([Points], [Title], [createdby])) AS PivotTable;
```

Based on your comment you will need to add a key to your source @table

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE( 
id int,
FieldName varchar(100), 
FieldValue varchar(max))

insert into @Table values(1,'Title','NewFrom')
insert into @Table values(1,'Points','4')
insert into @Table values(1,'createdby','5')

insert into @Table values(2,'Title','NewFrom2')
insert into @Table values(2,'Points','44')
insert into @Table values(2,'createdby','55')

insert into @Table values(3,'Title','NewFrom3')
insert into @Table values(3,'Points','444')
```

Then you can run the query:

```
SELECT   [Title],   [Points], [createdby]
FROM   @Table
PIVOT
(
       max(FieldValue) FOR [FieldName] IN ([Title], [Points], [createdby])
) AS P
```

Comment: in above answer it is only inserted Tittle rest are not not inserted. can you modify it for all. Also this columns are dynamic some times @table have only 2 or 3 . all columns are allowing as  null values. Also any idea to make update script as well?